# Induction proof of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom n k = 2^n -1 $

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction

> Prove by induction: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom n k = 2^n -1 $$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Today I wrote calculus exam, I had this problem given.

I have the feeling that I will get $0$ points for my solution, because I did this:

Base Case: $n=1$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{1} \binom 1 1 = 1 =  2^1 -1 .$$

Induction Hypothesis: for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom n k = 2^n -1 $$

Induction Step: $n \rightarrow n+1$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \binom {n+1} {k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom {n+1} {k} + \binom{n+1}{n+1} = 2^{n+1} -1$$

Please show me my mistake because next time is my last chance in this class.

Comment: The problem is that you prove nothing during the induction phase.

Comment: yeaaah, this is my problem i think. can you please give me more steps in between?

Comment: Another nitpick, your hypothesis is what you want to prove. You should say that there exists an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that for all $k\leq n$ the identity holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first mistake is that you stated the induction hypothesis incorrectly: it should be simply that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}k=2^n-1\;.\tag{1}$$

What you gave as induction hypothesis is actually the theorem that you’re trying to prove!

Now, assuming $(1)$ you want to prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}k=2^{n+1}-1\;.$$

This is an occasion when it’s **not** a good idea to split off the last term. Instead, use the Pascal’s triangle identity for binomial coefficients:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}k&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\left(\binom{n}k+\binom{n}{k-1}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n}k+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k-1}\\\\
&\overset{*}=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}k+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\\\\
&=\left(2^n-1\right)+\binom{n}0+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}k\\\\
&=2^n-1+1+2^n-1\\\\
&=2\cdot2^n-1\\\\
&=2^{n+1}-1\;.
\end{align*}$$

At the starred step I used the fact that $\binom{n}{n+1}=0$ to drop the last term of the first summation, and I did an index shift, replacing $k-1$ by $k$, in the second summation.

Comment: Brian, brilliant. my Bad, i am soo dumb. thank you so much

Comment: @doniyor: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

suppose that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom n k = 2^n -1 $$
then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \binom {n+1}{k} =\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\Bigg( \binom {n}{ k} +\binom{n}{k-1}\Bigg)=$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \binom {n}{ k} +\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k-1}=$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom {n}{ k}+\binom{n}{n+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom {n}{k}=$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom {n}{ k}+\binom{n}{n+1}+\binom{n}{0}+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom {n}{k}=$$
$$=2\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom {n}{ k}+\binom{n}{n+1}+\binom{n}{0}=$$
since $\binom{n}{n+1}=0, \binom{n}{0}=1$
$$=2\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom {n}{ k}+1=2(2^n-1)+1=2^{n+1}-2+1=2^{n+1}-1$$

Comment: wow, great. thanks Adi. there are so smooth and beautiful ways...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few points where I'd suspect someone could take issue with your answer:

The Induction Hypothesis is supposed to be the idea that given the hypothesis holds for a set of values from the base case up to an n that you could use that to prove the n+1 case.  You seem to imply that the Induction Hypothesis holds for all natural numbers which is a bit of an overstatement to my mind.

Lastly, where is the use of the induction hypothesis in the last step?  Where do you use the $2^n$-1 part that should be part of the solution.

---

$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \binom {n+1} {k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom {n+1} {k} + \binom{n+1}{n+1} = (n+1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom {n} {k} + 1 = (n+1)(2^n-1)+1 = n2^n-n+2^n-1+1 = 2^n(n+1)-n$ which still has to be simplified into the final result but this at least is using the hypothesis.

Comment: i just blindly wrote $2^{n+1}-1$. i didnot know how to come to solution thru binomials.